# Is it possible to control the size of attachments sent to my bot via Messenger?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger

When people share images via Messenger, those images are compressed, both by the client app on the device, and by Messenger's servers before storing in their CDN. If Messenger is being used as a channel to a Microsoft BotFramework bot, only at that point in the bot's incoming message do you get the link to that attachment.

This is understandable, given the volume of images shared every day by Messenger users, and those users are essentially getting free image storage.

However, we would like to use these images for further processing - text extraction, for example. By the time we get access to these images, the compression has rendered them unusable for this purpose (20-40kb) - at least from iPhones. Android appears to be more relaxed, but at around 150kb an image this is still a serious downsizing from a 2MB original photo.

This seems like a Facebook-controlled setting - is it possible to set a more forgiving compression ratio that is applied to incoming media?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this would be on the facebook end.  I am not aware of any way to circumvent this in the context of bot framework because by the time it gets to us, the image is formatted however facebook decided to format it.

Comment: Yep I was afraid of that Jason - I've also asked in Facebook's own ad community if there might be a way of setting this in a customisable way - say, by paying a fee to FB to not compress images sent to a given FB page or pages via Messenger.